# Can I fly to LA with JUST my work permit only?

Tags: visas, air-travel, paperwork, airport-security

My ID is expired for more than 1 year and I don't think it will get here in time for my trip in December. I only have my work permit card with me at this time that just got renewed. Can I only use that when I go to the airport or will I need to bring other documents? This will be my first time flying so I want to make sure I don't have any trouble when going on my trip.

Traveling from Texas to California

Comment: Welcome to TravelSE. We typically need a little more detail to be able to answer reliably. For example, where are you flying *from*? What is your citizenship?

Comment: Texas to California

Comment: How old are you?

Comment: Most airlines have details of acceptable forms of ID on their websites; an EAD card (work permit) should meet a requirement for state/federal-issued photo ID for a US internal flight, but I'm not going to say that it will meet all airlines' ID requirements because I don't know. As an example, here are Jet Blue's rules https://www.jetblue.com/help/identification-id-requirements

Comment: Which ID expired? Your passport? Your state driver's license/non-driver ID?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the purposes of TSA security checkpoints, an EAD (I-766) by itself is [acceptable ID](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/identification):

> Adult passengers 18 and over must show valid identification at the
> airport checkpoint in order to travel.
>
> [...]
>
> - U.S. Citizenship and Immigration Services Employment Authorization Card (I-766)

If you have a valid foreign passport, that is by itself acceptable ID too:

> - Foreign government-issued passport